# Tableview, how to disable reusablecell? (for testing purposes)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am currently using a tableview with reusablecells, but I want to disable this ( I know people dont recommend this, but I would like to see the performance difference). I've tried searching for the correct code, but the examples don't work for me.

Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Basically i dont want the cells to be reusable, i want the images/names to be stored in memory.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SökrutaCell


        cell.Söknamn.text = sökresultat[indexPath.row].displayname
        cell.Sökbild.image = UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash")


    return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images and names - you have to build separate cache logic that will do that for you.
Disabling dequeuing is definitely not the way to go.

You keep your cache outside somewhere in separate structures and then you pull data from that place in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

If you really, really want to do it - simply get an Array of `UITableViewCell`s and instead of `dequeueReusableCell` simply initialise Cells manually - then keep then in an Array.

But that's so wrong from so many different reasons... don't go this way - do it properly and build cache logic outside of View logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any part of my code above that I can change for them to not be reusable? I thought that maybe i could just change the "dequeueReusableCell" to something else, or maybe its more complicated than that? Sorry, i am a complete beginner at Swift.

Answer (score 0):

To disable cell reuse, you can replace this line

```
let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SökrutaCell
```

with this

```
let cell = SökrutaCell()
```

This will allocate a new cell object for every time a cell is requested.

Comment: Hey! I tried changing the code, but i got a fatal error at  "cell.Söknamn.text = sökresultat[indexPath.row].displayname" - Unexpecredly found nil while unrwapping an optional value. Do I have to replace "indexpath" with something?

Comment: This error seems unrelated to the original question or my answer. Usually this error means you are using a '!' operator, where you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Shortly before the error code, i get this code "Info: Ferch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile..../caches, errno:2  , could it be having trouble opening the cached file?

Comment: I'm sorry, this could mean anything. I don't know :(